# PC boots on its own without any explicit request randomly

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

so my desktop PC apparently sometimes just boots up without anyone being around to push the I/O button. This is kind of weirding me out, because I don't use anything which would wake up my device via Wake on Lan or something like this.

Ususally I have my PC unplugged after shutting it down to avoid stuff like this, but I thought I might just give it another try and now that it happened again, I want to check the root cause for this behaviour

I just checked my event viewers recorded System messages. There's one thing that might be interesting:

The last shutdown happened on 17th of April, 4:15:25 pm.

The first message of today, after the supposedly random boot, happened today, 18th of April, 4:15:56 pm. Given some time for the boot process, it seems like the two events are exactly 24 hours apart.

I also checked my WoL settings, apparently it was still turned on, so I disabled that, but I don't think this has to do with it necessarily.

That's all I could come up with for now, any solutions?

If there is data missing, I will happily provide it, I just don't know what might be missing.

Comment: Run `powercfg /lastwake` to find out what waked it up, for example the Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

Are there any Windows updates pending to install, and do you use hibernate (or shutdown without installing updates)?

I get this quite frequently on Windows 10, and I almost always use hibernate when I'm done with my PC. Turns out Windows is scheduling itself to power up so it can install updates while nobody is using the PC, but ultimately fails every time because my OS volume is Bitlocker protected. I'll just find my PC idle on the Bitlocker boot-time password prompt screen wasting electricity...

No power or GPO configuration I've come across stops this, even disabling wake timers. -- The only solution I've had yet is to use "Install updates and shutdown" to keep Windows happy.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a hardware fault. I too experienced such randomly auto reboots and it turned out to be a motherboard malfunctioning. You should check if it is a hardware malfunctioning.